# Grid read action method is not hitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my Kendo UI Grid the the `read.action()` method is not hitting. I have tried everything. Please help me if I have missed something.

When I debug, it is not even going to read.action method. In my index page, I am not doing anything, just returning the view. I can see it's going to the index method and returning a view, but it is not hitting read.action method.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BHEBS_Web.Models.ContractorModel>()
    .Name("ContractorGrid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Contractors_Read", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post)))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(contractor => contractor.Id);
        columns.Bound(contractor => contractor.ContractorName);
        columns.Bound(contractor => contractor.BHSISNum);
        columns.Bound(contractor => contractor.ContractorType);
    }) 
)

public ActionResult Contractors_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(GetContractors().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}

private static IEnumerable<ContractorModel> GetContractors()
{
    List<BHEBS_DAL.fContractor> lstContractors = BHEBS_BLL.Contractor.GetAllContractors();
    return lstContractors.Select(contractor => new ContractorModel
    {
        Id = contractor.Id,
        ContractorName = contractor.ContractorName,
        ContractorType = contractor.ContractorType,
        BHSISNum = contractor.BHSISNum
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contractors_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(GetContractors().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

You shouldn't need to add `.Type(HttpVerbs.Post)`, the datasource will do a HttpPost by default.

Also ensure all your scripts are being loaded properly:

[Kendo UI requires JQuery 1.9.1 to function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/prerequisites#supported-jquery-versions):

```
<script src="~/Script/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Ensure the Kendo scripts are loading in this order](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5#add-telerik-ui-for-aspnet-mvc-to-the-application):

```
<script src="~/Script/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Script/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#ContractorGrid").data("kendoGrid")
    grid.dataSource.read()
})</script>

Comment: Can you check the debugger in your browser to see what request the grid is sending to the action?

Comment: It is not calling the action method. its just going to index method and displaying empty grid

Comment: Please check if your kendo javascript files are being loaded properly

Comment: I have added all these references :

Comment: '<script src="~/Script/Jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Script/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/kendo.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Script/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Script/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="~/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'

Comment: Try removing `kendo.web.min.js`, you don't need both `kendo.web.min.js` and `kendo.all.min.js`. Also ensure there's no error loading the scripts when you run the application.

Comment: Also update your jquery to the latest version, Kendo requires at least 1.9.1

Comment: I did find the issue Nicholas, I have added the js files but aspnetmvc.min was not loading properly. Thanks a lot for the help